# Huawei Modem E173 Not Connecting on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, usb

Is their a new version of modem manager (0.6.0)? Help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same type of a wireless modem and I connect it using wvdial package. It's working for me.

See here for the connection procedure : http://linuxinternetworks.com/how-to-connect-mobile-broadband-in-the-ubuntu-linux/